# Facebook Social Plugin Comments not shown when directly linked to?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

I just set up Facebook social plugin comments on my site, but I'm having a little trouble with them. When I get a notification saying that someone commented on something I commented on, if I click on that link I see no comments, but if I reload the page without the ?fb_comment_id=... then I can see the comments.

For instance:

http://www.5crideshare.jessepollak.me/rides/17?fb_comment_id=fbc_10150513336718064_21937866_10150513339773064&ref=notif&notif_t=open_graph_comment#f82002554

shows no comments, but

http://www.5crideshare.jessepollak.me/rides/17

shows comments.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Thank you very much,

Jesse

Comment: Is my question helpful? If it solves your problem please accept the answer. If not, please give information. Thank you.

Comment: accepted the answer, but see my comment. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Facebook supposes that they are two different pages. While you are adding the plugin to your page, pay attention to `data-href` value.
Make your `data-href` value constant for the same page, although it may be requested with different URLs with extra querystrings.

When I look at your page source, clicked from notification:

```
<div class='fb-comments' data-href='http://www.5crideshare.jessepollak.me/rides/17?fb_comment_id=fbc_10150513336718064_21937866_10150513339773064&amp;ref=notif&amp;notif_t=open_graph_comment' data-num='{:posts=&gt;2}' data-width='500'></div>
</div>
```

On this page, `data-href` value should be without unnecessary querystrings. It should be like this same with clear one: `http://www.5crideshare.jessepollak.me/rides/17`

Comment: Oh, now I understand. I set the data-href with a call to request.url, so I I guess that's why it has the additional querystrings. Any idea how to remove the query strings from the request.url string?

I'm using Rails, by the way.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Just used request.url.split("?")[0]. Thanks again!