# Facebook comments breaking url ?fb_comment_id=xxxx

Tags: .htaccess, joomla1.5, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

I have problem on facebook wall I have a link to comment

```
http://loza.....pl/nowe/item/953-5-min-przed-koncem-swiata.html?fb_comment_id=fbc_10150440148781931_20104033_10150440188111931#f15a26d354fc36e -
```

facebook added something to url and comments are not visible...

When you go directly to:

```
http://loza.....pl/nowe/item/953-5-min-przed-koncem-swiata.html
```

everything is fine, fb comments are visible so I want to make a rewrite rule... on htaccess

any help...pls

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm facing the same problem now.

Comment: possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452529/facebook-social-plugin-comments-not-shown-when-directly-linked-to

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)fb_comment_id=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [L]
```

If the querystring contains a fb_comment_id, the visitor will be redirected to the requested page, but the **full** query string will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(^|&)fb_[^&]+(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1?%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```